# Regex exclude bracket symbol

Tags: regex

I am trying to use RegEx to find all cells in OO-calc with : [RB]Condition=New

the RB part is necessary, as other cells may get caught if it is not specified.

the RegEx that would work would be : [RB]Condi.*

however the brackets are read as a part of the expression, is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an escape character to treat it as an actual character.  For example `\[` would find all `[`.  I think the Regex you're looking for is `\[RB\]Condition=New`*.  The original Regex you had would find `RCondition=New` and `BCondition=New`.

*I'm not familiar with OO-calc, so I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: thanks, OO-calc = openoffice calc. Escaping it worked properly, thanks :)

Comment: @NRGdallas You're welcome.  If you use Regular Expressions frequently, I highly suggest reading up on them.  You can get a good overview in less than 30 minutes.  regular-expressions.info is a nice place to start.